# Change alpha component in a function returning a float *color

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I've got a function returning a (float *) color.
It works, until I tried to change the alpha component of one color, and now almost all colors have alpha issue, even if the color don't pass the test "if (alpha)".

eg:
float * colorTest = getColor(0); // don't give me the good result anymore, once any getColor(1) is called before.

```
float * getColor(float alpha) {
    float * col;

    if (val == 1)
        col = colorWhite; // colorWhite is a float *
    else if (val == 2)
        col = colorRed;
    else if (etc..)
        col = colEtc;

    if (alpha) {
        col[3] = alpha; // this doesn't works
    }

    return col;
}
```

I also have tried to change the alpha value through the col pointer, with same result:

```
if (alpha) {
    float *a;
    a = (float *)(&col + 3);
    *a = alpha;
}
```

Any advice?

### Edit

Got it to works, thx to hyde who told me that I was changing my global colors. (I was used to falsely considered float * as array)
So, I just copy the result in a second variable and then modify this new color.

```
float * getColor(float alpha) {
    float * col;
    float * tmp;

    if (val == 1)
        tmp = colorWhite; // colorWhite is a float *
    else if (val == 2)
        tmp = colorRed;
    else if (etc..)
        tmp = colEtc;

    memcpy(col, tmp, sizeof(float)*4);

    if (alpha) {
        col[3] = alpha; // this now works without issue
    }

    return col;
}
```

Comment: Has no one ever told you about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Just how are colors being represented in this code? It is highly unusual to use a `float` for a color value; the most common software representation (RGBA) is a packed, unsigned 32-bit value consisting of four bytes representing red, green, blue, and the alpha channel. However, there are other models for color such as CYMK, which is why knowing the representation ins important. Also, why are you using pointers to the values, rather than passing the values directly?

Comment: Also, you seen to be using 'alpha' solely as a representation of transparency, which isn't quite how the alpha channel works. Alpha refers to the opacity of the color value as a whole, and can be in a full range of values representing gradients of opacity.

Comment: Those pointers are arrays of 4 float (RGBA). I thought it was common to return a float *, as we can't return array in C.

Comment: Finally, as a design point, was there a specific reason why you are using a chain of `if()`/`else if()` for testing a specific value, rather than a `switch()` statement? Just curious.

Comment: it's only for a the exemple. I thought a switch case would obfuscate the question.

Comment: Is the choice of representation yours, or part of a library you are using? If it is your choice, why use `float`s?

Comment: It from a very old open source game. Color was designed that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (alpha) {
    col[3] = alpha; // this doesn't works
}
```

Here `col` points to one of your global colors. And then you change it.

Since color is small (4 floats, I assume), just pass values and forget pointers. Do this by defining struct

```
struct color {
    float component[4];
    // Or if you prefer: float r, g, b, a;
};
```

Especially on a 64 bit system, pointer is probably half the size of this struct, and has pointer dereference overhead, so performance-wise it's the basically the same. And pointers are always messier than values.

Once you have working code with struct values, then you can consider using pointers to optimize, eg. `const struct color *param` as function argument. But, this really is very small optimization with 4 floats. If the struct is passed in 2 registers, then forcing it to be in memory so you can pass a pointer in 1 register may even be a pessimization.

---

Additionally, you usually don't want to accidentally change the global data like these global colors, so make them const.

Comment: thx for the pointer reminder. See my updated question.